# Magento - How to trigger event (change user group) after purchasing a specific product

Tags: php, magento, usergroups

My question is how to trigger an action after a successful order (with ID 11)?

I read from previous questions that I need to create an observer for `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` but not much is explained after that.

Below is the code that (from the same previous question) I used to change the product:

```
$special_cat = 11; // Special product category
$customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
$lastOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
$order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order'); 
$order->load($lastOrderId);
$allitems = $order->getAllItems();
foreach($allitems as $item)
{
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
    $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
    if (in_array($special_cat, $categoryIds)) {
        $mem_group_id = $item->getSku();  // $item->getSku() is customer group name
        $customer_detail = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
        $customer_detail->setGroupId($mem_group_id);
        $customer_detail->save();
    }
}
```

Do I need to create an extension for this or do I need to edit the core files? Where should I create the Observer?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You need create extension for this. It's not a big deal. So you want change user group for a customer after order is success. Right ?. For this you need observe the checkout process and put your code in that. And you were right, `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` is the correct observer for this.

Here you go..

*app/code/local/Packagename/Modulename/etc/config.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Packagename_ModuleName>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Packagename_ModuleName>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
      <modulename>
        <class>Packagename_ModuleName_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>modulename_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </modulename>
    </models>
    <events>
      <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>model</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>modulename/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>changeUserGroup</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
            <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
          </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action_handler>
        </observers>
      </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

Here `Packagename_ModuleName_Model` is your new class. and `changeUserGroup` is your new method. Here only we will put our code for user group change things.
so,

*app/code/local/Packagename/Modulename/Model/Observer.php*

```
 <?php
    class Packagename_ModuleName_Model_Observer
    {

                public function changeUserGroup(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
                {
                    //$customer = $observer->getCustomer();

$special_cat = 11; // Special product category
$customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
$lastOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
$order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order'); 
$order->load($lastOrderId);
$allitems = $order->getAllItems();
foreach($allitems as $item)
{
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
    $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
    if (in_array($special_cat, $categoryIds)) {
        $mem_group_id = $item->getSku();  // $item->getSku() is customer group name
        $customer_detail = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
        $customer_detail->setGroupId($mem_group_id);
        $customer_detail->save();
    }
}
                }

    }
```

And finally enable your module in,

*app/etc/modules/Packagename_ModuleName.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Packagename_ModuleName>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Packagename_ModuleName>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Normally we get the details from `$observer` when we observe something. But in your case the `customer_id` and `order-id` is available in session. So we can get those things from session. That's it.

If you have any doubt please comment here.

Answer (score 1):

It's never a good practise to edit the core files. If you want to change the functionality of default Magento, you should override specific files. 
[Here is a good tutorial on overriding](http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/)

A much better way is to create an extension and observe specific events. In your case, observe **sales_order_place_after** event and check whether the order is containing product with ID 11 or not? If yes, then change the customer group.

For More info on observer [check this out.](http://www.solvingmagento.com/events-and-observers-a-magento-tutorial/)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

no need to create extension for it.

Just go to in your onepage_controller_action and add following code.

```
 $mem_catid = 982; //CATEGORY ID products to filter
$_customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
$lastOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
$order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order'); 
$order->load($lastOrderId);
$allitems = $order->getAllItems();
foreach($allitems as $item)
{
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
    $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
    if (in_array($mem_catid, $categoryIds)) {
        $mem_group_id = $item->getSku();  // $item->getSku() is customer group name
        $customer_detail = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
        $customer_detail->setGroupId(6);//add customer group id here which you want to set.
        $customer_detail->save();
    }
}
```